# Get count of rows in each table while having more than 1 tables

Tags: jquery

I have more then one tables on same page and want to add a line show count of each table as below.
I tried something but it gives sum of count of all table rows.

```
<table>
 <tr>
   <td>Some data</td>
   <td>More data</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
   <td>Some data</td>
   <td>More data</td>
 </tr>
</table>

<table>
 <tr>
   <td>Some data</td>
   <td>More data</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
   <td>Some data</td>
   <td>More data</td>
 </tr>
</table>

<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
 $().ready(function(){

  //I want to add a line after each table showing each table row count
  $("table").after(??? + " rows found.");
 });
</script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you need, without `.each()` loop, using only `after()`.

```
$("table").after(function(){
    return $('tr', this).length + " rows found.";    
});
```

***[The demo](http://jsfiddle.net/FFJ7w/3/)***

Answer (score 4):

```
$("table").each(function(){
    $(this).after($(this).find('tr').length + " rows found.");    
})
```

[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/FFJ7w/)

Comment: this is giving sum of rows in all tables which (4), after both table.

Comment: yeah..I didn't read yr question properly 1st time..Changed right then..if u pass function to `after` in that code..it'll give right result..

Answer (score 3):

You can get the row count quite easily like this:

```
// loop over all tables
$("table").each(function(){ 
    // get number of rows, uses jQuery's context parameters to speed things up
    // (it is apparently somewhat faster than using 'find' in most cases)
    var nrOfRows = $("tr", this).length;

    $(this).after(nrOfRows + " rows found");
});
```

[Working DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/jXPBx/)

**update** You can do it in less lines of course, I split it up to make it clearer using comments. You could just write:

```
$("table").each(function(){ 
    $(this).after($("tr", this).length + " rows found");
});
```

Answer (score 3):

What about this?

```
$("table").each(function(){
    $(this).after($(this).find('tr').length + " rows found.")
});
```

**EDIT**

To get the total from both tables after the last table:

```
$('table:last').after($('tr').length + " rows found.")
```

Comment: returns sum of rows in all tables not sum of rows in each table.

Comment: Sorry. Misunderstood your initial post. Try this?
`$('table:last').after($('tr').length + " rows found.")`

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest:

```
​$('table tbody').each(
    function(){
        var tfoot = $('<tfoot />', {'class' : 'rowSummary'}).insertBefore($(this)),
            tr = $('<tr />').appendTo(tfoot),
            len = $(this).find('tr').length,
            cell = $('<td />',{'colspan' : '2' }).text(len).appendTo(tr);
    });​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/WRnm3/1/).